# How can I send Email By TransportBuilder

Tags: magento2, send-mail

I want to send Email By TransportBuilder.
But I got Exception :  Required parameter `theme_dir` was not passed .

I found  in 
`/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Theme.php` Line 66.

```
$params['theme_dir'] = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(
                    ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
                    $theme->getFullPath()
                );
```

It result is empty. 
So it will got this exception. 
And I print $theme->getFullPath()
I got

```
crontab/Magento/luma
```

How can I fix it?

My Send Email Code :
        $post['name'] = 'Name';
    $post['email'] = 'whoami@gmail.com';
    $content = 'It content';

```
$post['comment'] = $content;
$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($post);
$transportBuilder = $this->objectManager->create('\Magetools\SohoAuto\Model\Repository\TransportBuilder');
$transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->template) // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($emailAry)
        ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: can we have look at your Email code ?

Comment: if it works accept the ans

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->state->emulateAreaCode(
   \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
    [$this->dataHelper, 'sendExportedEmail'],
    [$rule, $csvFile]
);
```

I use this code, you cron tab env maybe is wrong, so change the area code fron other to frontend.